# Select documents that don't have some keys in CouchDB

Tags: couchdb

Having an article document with an embedded array of tags, how to select articles that don't contain some specific tags?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty easy to create views which exclude documents which don't contain some specific tags. This is documented here: [CouchDB Wiki: View Snippets: Retrieving documents without a certain field](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_Snippets#Retrieving_documents_without_a_certain_field).

However, I suspect what you really want is a way to do this dynamically, by having a single view to which you could pass a parameter containing the tag(s) you wanted to exclude. That's pretty tricky, and I don't know how one would do it. If that's the case, I suggest you post a question to the [couchdb-user mailing list](http://couchdb.apache.org/community/lists.html) or to the IRC channel (irc://irc.freenode.net/couchdb). It's an active and helpful community so someone will definitely try to help you figure this out.

FWIW, I did a quick search and found this interesting idea: [Using _list for query post-processing](http://www.mail-archive.com/user@couchdb.apache.org/msg03419.html). There were no responses, but it's an interesting idea and possibly worth exploring.

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as @AviFlax suggests, using a _list to post process your view will work.
Note that you can send arbitrary parameters to the view, and get them in the list inisde the req.query object.

Example:

```
GET http://host/db/_design/ddoc/_list/a-list/a-view?some="thing"
```

The arbitrary parameter some, can be obtained within the list function, and thus used for filtering or other processing.

```
function(head, req) {
   var some = req.query.some
   ....
}
```